# Why my Polynomial model has this spike?

Tags: regression, polynomial

How can I explain the **spike** in my Poly model after using the polynomial 3rd degree?
My dataset consist of the X variables external facctores (x1,x2...xk) and Y which is a target variable. For a polynomial I am not using interactions. I am using only the degrees. So i have x1, x1**2, x1**2 and so on for all values which might have a degrees. 
[image]

 Meanwhile OLS is quite ok 
[image]

And here is my OLS regression output 
[image]

Comment: There are lots of polynomials. Can you explain which polynomial basis you used? How is the OLS model computed? It's clearly not a single line in the space of the $x$ axis of the plot.

Comment: Sure I will edit the question

Comment: The spike is the least of your problems. This model is grossly overfit: you use far too many variables for the limited number of observations you have. There are many indications that conditions needed to apply OLS reliably don't hold (look, in particular, at the kurtosis of the residuals).

Comment: @whuber thank you for observation. But anyways my data is not normaly distributed so the kurtosis is not preoccupying me. I have checked the main assumptions of OLS which are multicollenearity, endegen. and autocorrelation of residuals are all ok.

Comment: Have you looked at the huge condition number?  What you have posted is a useless model due to the overfitting and multicollinearity, unless your sole objective is to describe your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. Look at your "polynomial" model output. Find the coefficient that is orders of magnitude higher than the others. This is where the model is so finely adjusted, that there is a single observation for one or more cofficients uniquely determine its value. Consider yourself lucky that the observation you have overfit is obviously visible in the plot - and consider further it's probably happening in a few other places.

The best solution is just to fit a smarter model. I don't know anything about your problem, but it's curious that you have adjusters such as "8marzo" i.e. the 8th of March. One wonders why you effectively delete the observation by adjusting for it specially.

But in cases such as this, analysts have often advocated for a ridge (L2 penalty) regression to reduce the high variance of coefficients in overadjusted prediction models.

You might liken it to the following example in OLS:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sort(rnorm(100))
i <- 1:100 == 100 ## indicator for 100th observation
y <- rnorm(100, x) ## no relation to i at all

fit <- lm(y ~ x + i)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, predict(fit))
```

[image]

Comment: How can you tell which coefficients are large when you know nothing about the values of the underlying variables??

Comment: True, one assumes they are standardized in a sensible way, and if they are not, then they can be without impacting the inference/analysis/observed issue here.

Comment: @AdamO I really liked your answer however I didn't quite get the points of overfitting and fine adjustment. Could you please explain in a simpler way? Thank you

Comment: @AdamO btw i have used also LAsso and Ridge models. They have set some of my variables to 0. Variables set to 0 are constant, and 2 other dummy variables

Comment: @Amirgiano the issue seems to stem from a lack of experience in analysis - which is ok. Even in the polynomial setting, you can attempt to add variables one after the other - or remove them in a similar fashion - to gain insight into your model. It's tedious and every bit worthwhile.

Comment: Given the large range of the coefficient estimates, the assumption of standardization is not tenable.

Comment: @AdamO so you mean there is a variable which has a huge coefficent which is actually makes that spike. The only way to find it is a backward selection technique. Correct?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way to identify a variable contributing to an anomaly is to identify the record or records exhibiting that anomaly and inspect the values of all variables in those records.  That's quick and easy.

Comment: Indeed I did something similar. I was thinking that one variable might to that. I used it as a mediator. I have regressed the media variables' total with that variable and used the regression predictions as a new variable. Then my polynomial model had 0.38 of the RMSE